# Dojo/Spring DateTextBox initialization fails with Date value, works with String?

Tags: java, javascript, spring, dojo

I'm struggling with getting a Date value back and forth from a web form to the Spring controller.   Everything was working fine with this value passed as a String, but since it was logically a "date" value, I changed it to a Date and everything went kerflooey.

I tried the fix indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367660/how-to-pass-java-date-object-to-dojo-datetextbox-through-spring-mvc-and-back-to), but it did not work.

Here's the error I get at runtime (from "locale.js"):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object 2/28/13 has no method 'getMonth'
```

The page is built using a JSP with Spring Forms tags (form:form, form:input, etc) and the client-side validation is done using SpringValidation decorators which rely on the Dojo Javascript library.

Here's the field that I'm passing:

```
@NotEmpty
@DateTimeFormat(style="S-")
private Date startDate;
```

Here's the Javascript/Dojo client side validation code:

```
Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ElementDecoration({
    elementId : "startDate",
    widgetType : "dijit.form.DateTextBox",
    widgetAttrs : {
        missingMessage : parms.required,
        invalidMessage : parms.wrongFormatMessage,
        required : true,
        regExp : parms.textFieldPattern }
}));
```

And here's the actual form tag:

```
<form:input id="startDate" path="startDate" />
```

Anybody have any ideas?   It's happening somewhere in the bowels of Dojo/Spring, and I'm not sure why it would fail if I pass it a "date" but work if I pass it a "string" containing a date value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be the @DateTimeFormat of the Date property on the form backing object.   This didn't work:

```
@DateTimeFormat(style="S-")
private Date startDate;
```

But this did:

```
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
private Date startDate;
```

Apparently Javascript and the Dojo DateTextBox are VERY fussy about date formats.